# Как узнать от какого пользователя запущен apache?

Tags: ssh, freebsd, apache2

Собственно сам вопрос.Сервер на FreeBSD с Apache/2.2.25. Есть доступ по SSH.

Нужна команда-ssh которая покажет имя пользователя ?

Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ps auxwwww | grep apache

или

> ps auxwwww | grep httpd

в первой колонке будет имя пользователя.

Comment: ps auxwwww | grep httpdСпасибо.

Comment: зачем wwww? достаточно ps aux

Answer (score 1):

whoami

(минимальное количество символов в ответе - 20минимальное количество символов в ответе - 20минимальное количество символов в ответе - 20минимальное количество символов в ответе - 20)